$KO \wedge C\eta \simeq KU$
I have seen that there is a cofiber sequence $\Sigma KO \xrightarrow{\eta} KO \xrightarrow{c} KU$, where $\eta$ is the first Hopf map and $c$ is complexification. I have also seen that this holds for connective covers. How does one prove this? I can see how to show that $\pi_*(KO \wedge C\eta) \cong \pi_*KU$ (at least up to extension), but I don't know how to prove this at the level of spectra and can't seem to find a good resource. Any help is appreciated

I don't have a reference, but this result is generally known as Wood's theorem. Maybe you'll have more luck searching for that.

@BenSteffan I have been looking it up as Wood's Theorem to no avail, unfortunately.

Here's Wood's original paper, but I have my doubts that it will be very useful. Looking at that paper, I think there might be a chance that this could be found in Karoubi's text on $K$-theory, but this, too, would definitely not be on the level of spectra. One result in the book is referenced to the Wood paper, but I cannot tell whether it is related to this question pretty much at all.

The "modern" perspective for obtaining Wood's equivalence is explained in section 3 of this paper.
Briefly, the idea is to use the fact that $KU$ is a $C_2$-spectrum by complex conjugation, and that for a finite spectrum $X$, we have $(KU \otimes X)^{hC_2} \simeq KO \otimes X$.  It then suffices to show that $KU \otimes C\eta \simeq KU \oplus KU$ as $C_2$-spectra, where the action on the right hand side is by swapping the two summands (and acting trivially on each individually).  Then, taking homotopy fixed points we get $KO \otimes C\eta \simeq KU$, as desired.
To show that $KU \otimes C\eta \simeq KU \oplus KU$, we can use Bott periodicity to reduce to the case $KU_0 C\eta \cong KU_0 \oplus KU_0$.  Then all you would need to do is calculate $KU_0 C\eta$ as the rank 2 permutation representation for $C_2$.  You can probably do this directly, but the "formal groups" approach is to note that $C\eta \simeq \Sigma^{-2} \mathbb{C}P^2$ and then calculate instead $KU^0 \mathbb{C}P^2$, which has an interpretation as certain functions on $\widehat{\mathbb{G}_m}$.  All this is explained in the reference I linked above.
Alternatively, there is also another argument by Atiyah found here
